# Essential supremum of a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose  $f\colon(X,\mu)\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable. Let $S$ be the set of all real $\alpha$ such that

$\mu (f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty]))=0$

If $S=\emptyset$, put $\beta=\infty$. If $S\neq \emptyset$, put $\beta=\inf S$.

My question:

is $\beta \leq f$ or $f\leq \beta$?

I'm confused.

Thanks you all.

Comment: Hint: Show that $\mu(f^{-1}((\beta,\infty]))=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

As an aside, note that $x \in f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty])$  **iff** $f(x) > \alpha$.

Take $f = (-1)1_{\{0\}} + 1_{ \{1\}}$. Then $S=[0,\infty]$ and
$\beta = 0$. However neither $\beta \le f$ nor
 $\beta \ge f$ is true.

However, we do have $\beta \le f(x)$ for ae. $x$. This follows by taking $\beta_n \in S$ such that $\beta_n \downarrow \beta$. The sets $f^{-1}((\beta_n, \infty])$ are non-decreasing, hence $\mu (f^{-1}((\beta_n, \infty]) ) \to \mu (f^{-1}((\beta, \infty]) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If we should only choose the right side, an example may be useful. Let $f=x$ on $[0,2]$ and 2 for $x>2$. Then $\beta=2$ and the inequality is obvious.